# Match increasing/incrementing number patterns in regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

Can anyone assist me with how to match increasing numbers with the help of regex?

I have thousands of random 10-digit numbers, and out of those, I want to find out numbers in increasing sequence that can be single digit, double digit or triple digit.

**Example:**

Please note that **no space** is required and **x** denotes a random digit.

1. xxxx 1 2 3 4 5 6 (single digit in increasing pattern)
2. xxxx 81 82 83 (double digits in increasing pattern)
3. xxxx 810 811 (triple digits in increasing pattern)

In some cases, the increasing sequence of numbers may be in the middle or at the start of the number:

1. 62 63 64 xxxx
2. xx 62 63 64 xx

I tried using some basic regex and manually inserting number in my regex itself, but this is not efficient and time consuming.

Suppose I am looking for pattern like

- xxxx 81 82 83

I tried `\d{4}(\d)1\12\13`

> 1. `\d` to match a digit
> 2. `{4}` to match 4 random digits
> 3. `(\d)` to capture a digit and put that in group #1
> 4. `1` to match digit 1
> 5. `\1` to repeat the in group #1
> 6. `2` to match digit 2
> 7. `3` to match digit 3

Then I will manually change **1 2 3** to **2 3 4** or **3 4 5** and look for the results. This will take me a lot of time to reach what I want.

Comment: Can you use any programming language apart from notepad? Kindly do let us know on same.

Comment: This is not a suitable task for regex. Use a programming language instead.

Comment: Regex doesn't do math (at least not in any reasonable way). Cast your input to int and sort them.

Comment: Have a look into [Python Script Plugin for Notepad++](https://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/). To find usage examples just search Stack Overflow for e.g. [\[regex\]\[notepad++\] python script](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bregex%5D+%5Bnotepad%2B%2B%5D+python+script) or [\[regex\]\[notepad++\] pythonscript](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bregex%5D+%5Bnotepad%2B%2B%5D+pythonscript)

Comment: Hello guys, apologies for not mentioning any programming language. This is something unusual for me and I have the data in Excel and to use the regex expressions I am using notepad++ find option. It may sound weird but this is how I am doing it, any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: *"no space is required"*: then how will you whether `123` means `12 3` or `1 23` or `1 2 3`?

Comment: *"I have the data in Excel"*: Excel is much more powerful than notepad++ when it comes to comparing numbers. Why not look for a solution in Excel? You can even program there with VBA... If that interests you, please rewrite your question and provide information how your data is structured in Excel, with an example, and corresponding desired output in Excel.

Answer (score -2):

Although you have not specified the programming language other than
notepad, here is a perl solution just for information:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# example of 1-digit increasing numbers
$str="99123450";
if ($str =~ /(\d)(??{ $1 + 1 })(??{ $1 + 2 })(??{ $1 + 3 })/) {
    print "$&\n";
}

# example of 2-digit increasing numbers
$str="012616263012";
if ($str =~ /(\d{2})(??{ $1 + 1 })(??{ $1 + 2 })/) {
    print "$&\n";
}
```

It will output:

```
1234
616263
```

- The perl regex `(??{ expression })` is substituted with the result
  of `expression` at runtime to be used as a part of regex pattern.
- The perl variable `$1` is assigned to the 1st capture group.
- The perl variable `$&` holds the matched substring.